# Cassandra Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native

Tags: java, cassandra, jna

I am having Cassandra version 3.9 on CentOS 7.
While starting Cassandra Server, I'm getting error like this::

> TRACE [MemtableFlushWriter:1] 2017-05-15 04:25:49,735 LogTransaction.java:264 - Closing transaction log [mc_txn_flush_3f6a46f0-3961-11e7-87b4-0728ea39fb0d.log in /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377]
>   ERROR [main] 2017-05-15 04:25:49,745 CassandraDaemon.java:747 -
>   Exception encountered during startup java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.sun.jna.Native    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:403)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.forceBlockingFlush(SystemKeyspace.java:793)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.removeTruncationRecord(SystemKeyspace.java:639)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.invalidate(ColumnFamilyStore.java:541)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.invalidate(ColumnFamilyStore.java:517)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.lambda$unloadLegacySchemaTables$341(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:137)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator$$Lambda$93/1308179535.accept(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]  at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.unloadLegacySchemaTables(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:137)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.migrate(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:83)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:254)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:730)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]

There is a solution to this problem ([Cassandra Startup failure on ARM64 machine (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077441/cassandra-startup-failure-on-arm64-machine-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-coul)
), Soultion suggests changes in **cassandra-env.sh**. I tried it but it is not working for me.

I checked with these options (separately) in **cassandra-env.sh**

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/tech/cassandra/tmp"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/cassandra/tmp"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/cassandra/tmp"
```

even tried with

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.boot_without_jna=true"
```

But no change in the problem.

And I changed cassandra logger to TRACE, but it is showing the same error log as before there was no TRACE. The file(jna-4.0.0.jar) is present in lib folder (/usr/share/cassandra/lib). I am unable to find what the actual reason is.

The reasons for not working for me are like:

1. cassandra-env.sh is loaded by server. (If it loading how do I check, whether it is loaded or not)
2. There might be some other problem.

Someone, Please let me out from this.

Comment: can you provide classpath details? Also which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Java version 1.8.0_45, I don't know about CLASS_PATH, how do I get it?

Comment: /usr/share/cassandra is CLASSPATH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally the problem with jna-4.0.0.jar.

The file jna-4.0.0.jar in lib is not initializing, so I changed the file by creating symbolic link to jna.jar.

```
sudo yum install jna

sudo ln -s (JAVA_PATH)/usr/share/java/jna.jar (CASSANDRA_PATH)/usr/share/cassandra/lib
```

Then It produced some errors regarding **tmp**, solved with previous solutions.

Regarding JNA, there are already some questions over there, but those are not specific.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Clean up (rm -rf *) of  the /tmp folder or the folder which '-Djava.io.tmpdir' points to

Answer (score 0):

After I upgraded Java, the Cassandra couldn't start. I fixed it by.

1.
mkdir -p /var/lib/cassandra/tmp
chown cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/cassandra/tmp

2.
Add below parameter to the end of the file /cassandra-env.sh
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/cassandra/tmp"

Then restarted Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

For those of the future...

I see the NoClassDefFound in the system.log file.

I tried the tmp changes to no avail. Then I looked at

```
sudo journalctl -u cassandra.service
```

And I see

```
/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

So that my be helpful to look at.