# couldn't connect to server in cassandra on centos6.9

Tags: python, cassandra, centos6

I am using VPS with centos 6.9. and I am new to cassandra. i have installed cassandra 3.0 using the following link:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/install/installRHEL.html

but when try to connect cassandra using python cassandra-driver using this:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
def get_cluster_connection_session():
    cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1',], port=9042)
    session = cluster.connect()
    return session
```

it gives me following error:

```
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

1) **python --version** gives me following output:

```
Python 2.7.6
```

2) **java -version** gives me following output:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

3) **sudo service cassandra status** gives me:

```
cassandra (pid  15193) is running...
```

Do i need to make any changes in **cassandra.yaml** file? if yes, can you please tell me what changes i need to make in **cassandra.yaml** file?

So can someone please help me to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try a telnet? `telnet 127.0.0.1 9042` connection refused already tells you that there is something listening on that port but didn't accept the connection.

Comment: can you run `nodetool status` just to see what's going on with your cluster.

Comment: @questionare, I have tried telnet `127.0.0.1 9042` which gives me following output:

` Trying 127.0.0.1... '

' telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused '

Comment: @MarkoŠvaljek Somehow **nodetool status** is not working.. gives me following output:
    ` Error: The node does not have system_traces yet, probably still bootstrapping'

Comment: do you see something in the system.log of cassandra? It looks like your instance might not have even started.

Comment: System.log gives me this:
`
ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:2] 2017-04-17 11:56:21,521 CassandraDaemon.java:205 - Exception in thread Thread[MemtableFlushWriter:2,5,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.memory.MemoryUtil.allocate(MemoryUtil.java:97) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.Memory.<init>(Memory.java:74) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory.<init>(SafeMemory.java:32) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]

Answer (score 1):

More or less it's all described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34063341/7413631

Follow the steps from the answer and let me know if you're stuck somewhere.

Add the options to `cassandra-env.sh` file.

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/cassandra/tmp"
```

Also make sure the `/home/cassandra/tmp` is created and that cassandra process had all the rights on it.

Comment: thanks it works. but still i am not able to open **cqlsh**.. it gives me following error.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 163, in <module>
    from cqlshlib import cql3handling, cqlhandling, pylexotron, sslhandling
    ImportError: No module named cqlshlib

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197362/unable-to-open-cqlsh-apache-cassandra-importerror-no-module-named-cqlshlib sorry for delay had to take care of the baby ;)

Comment: sorry for late reply. i have gone through the link you gave but when i installed **cqlsh** using **pip install cqlsh**. cqlsh is open but not able to connect to any servers, giving me same error which i was getting earlier. but without **cqlsh**, cassandra working fine. i can Insert data to tables. but still **cqlsh** issue is there. do i need to restart the cassandra after installation? because i have stopped cassandra service and again started the service after installation.

Comment: If Cassandra is running then cqlsh should also be able to connect. So basically even after installing the `cqlsh` you are getting `No module named cqlshlib`. Hm I would try to restart the whole machine then, But just as a confirmation the error is still 100% the same? Can you provide how you are using cqlsh i.e. command line call?

Comment: No i not getting error `No module named cqlshlib`. i am getting `Unable to connect to any servers`. and to start `cqlsh` , i am just writing `cqlsh` in command prompt.

Comment: Can you try to go to folder where you installed cassandra and just run `./bin/cqlsh` .... just to see what happens?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell you temporary i have uninstalled `cqlsh` , which i have installed using `pip install cqlsh`,  because i am working on some other part of project, i just need to insert data into cassandra tables and i am getting those inserted data by API. but as you said, i have tried top open cassandra command line by writing `cqlsh`. but it gives me following error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 163, in <module>
    from cqlshlib import cql3handling, cqlhandling, pylexotron, sslhandling
ImportError: No module named cqlshlib`

Comment: I guess you'll have to go then and check the answers out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197362/unable-to-open-cqlsh-apache-cassandra-importerror-no-module-named-cqlshlib but then again if it works for the scope that you need (app usage) I'm guessing you are good then ;) Anyway thanks, just wanted to follow up

Comment: yeah Marko, its working fine for me right now. and thank you very much for your help as you saved my lots of time. and i will get back to you on this topic, if i need your help. thanks again :)